# How to use exists, findOne and other GraphRepository methods, taking id as argument?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

**Let us assume following:**

1). We have two entities:

```
@NodeEntity
public class A {    
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@NodeEntity
public class B {    
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    ...
}
```

2). We have two appropriate repositories:

```
public interface ARepository extends GraphRepository<A> {
    ...    
}

public interface BRepository extends GraphRepository<B> {
    ...    
}
```

3). And we have following nodes in database:

- A with id=1
- B with id=2

---

**Case a:** Now assume we need to check whether A with id=2 is exists:

```
ARepository.exists(2)
```

I expect that it will return `false`, since A with id=2 isn't exists. But it returns `true`, since it tries to find among all ids, not only among A nodes.

**Case b:** Or maybe we need to find B with id=1:

```
BRepository.findOne(1);
```

I expect that it returns `null` or throws appropriate exception, informing that B with id=1 isn't exists. But it throws unexpected for me `PersistentEntityConversionException`.

---

**Hence questions:**

- How can we use aforementioned operations with expected behavior?
- May be there is workaround?

Comment: Which version of sdn?

Comment: I use spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.3.1.RELEASE. It has transitive dependency on spring-data-neo4j:3.3.1.RELEASE.